# Downloading language model in Spacy breaks in docker

Tags: docker, spacy

So my docker file has the following line

```
RUN python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

Which throws an error stating thinc module is not found.

So, I decided to add the following line above the previous line.

```
RUN pip install thinc
```

When I compile I get the following error.

```
Step 30/48 : RUN pip install thinc
 ---> Running in 7ba293263245
Collecting thinc
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/25/99/e21c2a1622c193b2c93a628496fea4525a0ce93e3b47f3cb06559b6ff3ee/thinc-7.4.3.tar.gz (1.3MB)
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    BLIS_COMPILER? None
    WARNING: pip versions <19.3 (currently installed: 9.0.1) are unable to detect binary wheel compatibility for blis. To avoid a source install with a very long compilation time, please upgrade pip with `pip install --upgrade pip`.

    If you know what you're doing and you really want to compile blis from source, please set the environment variable BLIS_REALLY_COMPILE=1.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 157, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 198, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 248, in run_setup
        DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
      File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 278, in run
        return func()
      File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 246, in runner
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 47, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "/tmp/easy_install-v4oqr4r6/blis-0.7.3/setup.py", line 219, in <module>
        "cython>=0.25",
    SystemExit: 1

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1101, in run_setup
        run_setup(setup_script, args)
      File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 251, in run_setup
        raise
      File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 99, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 198, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 99, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 169, in save_modules
        saved_exc.resume()
      File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 144, in resume
        six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
      File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/six.py", line 685, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 157, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 198, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 248, in run_setup
        DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
      File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 278, in run
        return func()
      File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 246, in runner
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 47, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "/tmp/easy_install-v4oqr4r6/blis-0.7.3/setup.py", line 219, in <module>
        "cython>=0.25",
    SystemExit: 1

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-_lc_0t4n/thinc/setup.py", line 276, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-_lc_0t4n/thinc/setup.py", line 272, in setup_package
        cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext_subclass},
      File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 315, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
      File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 361, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 850, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1122, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1134, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 429, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 665, in easy_install
        return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
      File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 695, in install_item
        dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
      File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 876, in install_eggs
        return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
      File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1115, in build_and_install
        self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
      File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1103, in run_setup
        raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-_lc_0t4n/thinc/
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 20.2.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

The image is

FROM centos/python-36-centos7

Comment: You probably need to upgrade pip (in the docker image) first.  'pip upgrade pip' or whatever the command is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

before you install python packages add the following line
RUN pip install --upgrade pip